# How does DataFrame.interpolation() work in its source code?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, github, interpolation, data-cleaning

Since I could not find the declarations of the single methods of DataFrame.interpolation()'s "method"-parameter, I am asking here:

How does pandas' DataFrame.interpolation() work in relation to the amount of rows it considers, is it just the row before the NaNs and the row right after?
Or is it the whole DataFrame (how does that work at 1 million rows?)

If you already know where to look, feel free to share the link to the source-code (since https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/06d230151e6f18fdb8139d09abf539867a8cd481/pandas/core/frame.py#L10916 doesnt include the "method"'s declarations (for example "polynomial").

Answer (score 0):

I found the attached in `core/missing.py`.

My interpretation is that interpolation is either done with `np.interp` or, if method is specified and only available in scipy, with `_interpolate_scipy_wrapper`. A function which I could not locate but a reasonable guess is that it is a wrapper for scipy.

```py
if method in NP_METHODS:
        # np.interp requires sorted X values, #21037

        indexer = np.argsort(indices[valid])
        yvalues[invalid] = np.interp(
            indices[invalid], indices[valid][indexer], yvalues[valid][indexer]
        )
    else:
        yvalues[invalid] = _interpolate_scipy_wrapper(
            indices[valid],
            yvalues[valid],
            indices[invalid],
            method=method,
            fill_value=fill_value,
            bounds_error=bounds_error,
            order=order,
            **kwargs,
        )

    yvalues[preserve_nans] = np.nan
```